# Why is this sequence relatively compact in $L^1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness, bounded-variation

I am currently reading [this paper from 1973](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-186-00/S0002-9947-1973-0335758-1/S0002-9947-1973-0335758-1.pdf).

In short, one has given a linear continuous operator $P : L^1([0,1]) \to L^1([0,1])$ with ||P||=1 and for $f \in L^1$ a family of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $f_n = P^n f$. Therefore it holds

$$||f_n|| \leq ||f||$$
and it is shown that
$$ \limsup_{k\to \infty} \bigvee_0^1 f_{Nk} \leq c ||f|| $$
where $ \bigvee_0^1 $ denotes the total variation, $0<c<1$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

It is then said (without explanation) that the set $$C:=\{f_{Nk} \mid k\in \mathbb{N} \}$$ is relatively compact in $L^1$, and because of
$$ \{ f_k \mid k\in \mathbb{N} \} \subset \bigcup_{i=0}^{N-1} P C$$
the set 
$$\{ f_k \mid k\in \mathbb{N} \}$$ is also relatively compact.

I do not see why $C$ is relatively compact, nor why $ \bigcup_{i=0}^{N-1} P C$ is relatively compact. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: $C$ seems to be bounded in $BV(0,1)$ - the space of functions with bounded variation - and as such is relatively compact in $L^1$.

Comment: @daw could you explain why or give a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you post, I read $C$ is bounded in $BV$ norm, i.e., the function of bounded variation.

If you know Sobolev space, you could just think $BV$ is the relaxation of $W^{1,1}$ and hence similar to $W^{1,1}$ space, bounded sequence in $BV$ will compact in $L^1$, and even in $L^q$ for any $q<N/(N-1)$ where $N$ is the dimension of space.

For reference, check out Theorem 4 at page 176 in [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849371570) book.